# Чем определяется кодировка строковых констант (литералов)

Tags: c++, c, кодировка

В сети и здесь, на SO, довольно много материала о работе с кодировками и локалями. Но почему-то нет вразумительной информации о кодировке строковых констант (литералов).

```
const char * text = "Какая ваша кодировка?";
```

Чем определяется кодировка строковых литералов: кодировкой файла с исходником, опциями компилятора или чем-то еще? Что на эту тему говорит стандарт? Как достоверно узнать кодировку строковых литералов на этапе компиляции (может макросы какие есть)? А в рантайме?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Данный ответ посвящён практике применения Microsoft Visual Studio.

Хорошего кроссплатформенного решения я, к сожалению, не знаю.

- Для файлов-исходников в неюникодных кодировках, строка интерпретируется как строка в ANSI-кодировке. Для русскоязычных систем это CP 1251. Это выполняется даже если для файла исходника задекларирована другая кодировка! При компиляции на системе с другой ANSI-кодировкой результат будет отличаться.
- Для файлов-исходников в юникодных кодировках, кодировка строки также Unicode.

  - Если при этом строка «узкая» (то есть, типа `char[]`), то строка будет сконвертирована в ANSI-кодировку с теми же последствиями.
  - Если при этом строка «широкая» (то есть, типа `wchar_t[]`), то строка останется как есть, то есть, правильной.

Это означает, что нужно использовать

- либо юникодную кодировку исходников + широкие строки,
- либо узкие строки в ANSI-кодировке с потерей компилируемости под нерусскими системами,
- либо кодировать литералы числовыми константами.

---

Как выяснилось в результате длительной дискуссии с @ixSci и @Abyx, Visual Studio 2015 ведёт себя немного по-другому: в случае кодировки файла utf-8 и узкой строки, в строке таки окажется utf-8. Но в случае кодировки файла utf-16 (ucs-2), результат прежний: попытка сконвертировать в ANSI (которая может и провалиться).

---

**Обновление:**

Visual Studio 2015 и старше конвертирует строки во внутренний формат. Конвертация определяется набором символов исходного файла (source character set), из которого символы конвертируются во внутренний формат (на текущий момент это utf-8). Набор символов, т. е., по сути, кодировка исходного файла определяется следующим образом

- Если файл содержит [BOM](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2), этим самым однозначно определяется его кодировка.
- В противном случае, если файл выглядит как файл в utf-16 (Visual Studio производит прикидку этого по первым восьми байтам) big/little endian, то это считается его кодировкой.
- В противном случае, если при компиляции (или в настройках проекта) указан ключ `/source-charset`, указанная в этом ключе кодировка и считается кодировкой входного файла.
- В противном случае, кодировкой входного файла считается системная кодовая страница (т. е., ANSI). Обратите внимание, что это не самый лучший вариант, т. к. одни и те же байты исходников при этом могут по-разному интерпретироваться на разных системах.

Следующая важная вещь — это набор символов времени выполнения (execution character set). Это, по сути, кодировка, в которую будут сконвертированы *узкие* строковые/символьные литералы (объявленные без префикса) при записи в выполняемый файл, и которые программа «увидит», если просканирует строки по байтам. Если при компиляции указан ключ `/execution-charset`, это и будет искомым набором символов. Если нет, в качестве набора символов используется текущая кодовая страница.

Обратите внимание, что вы можете указать ключ `/utf-8`, который установит одним махом оба набора символов в utf-8.

Ещё один набор символов — широкий набор символов времени выполнения (wide execution character set) — используется для конвертации *широких* символьных/строковых литералов. Он в MS Visual Studio неизменен и совпадает с utf-16.

Документация: [Visual C++ Team Blog / New Options for Managing Character Sets in the Microsoft C/C++ Compiler](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/02/22/new-options-for-managing-character-sets-in-the-microsoft-cc-compiler/).

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59783/discussion-on-answer-by-vladd------).

Answer (score 5):

Кодировка такой строки:

```
const char * text = "Какая ваша кодировка?";
```

Определяется исключительно кодировкой файла, в котором содержится данное определение. Начиная с C++11 можно явно указать, что хотите видеть строку в unicode, для этого есть следующие префиксы: u(UCS-2), u8(UTF-8) и U(UCS-4). Пример:

```
const char * text = u8"Какая ваша кодировка?";
```

Теперь текст гарантировано содержит строку в utf-8, вне зависимости от компилятора(если он поддерживает стандарт, разумеется)

Узнать кодировку макросами или другим «волшебством», насколько я знаю, — нельзя. Обычный совет, это не использовать не-английский текст в исходниках вообще. Так будет меньше головной боли, храните текст в отдельных файлах и читайте их по мере надобности.

Comment: "Определяется исключительно кодировкой файла" это требование стандарта или так принято у всех компиляторов?

Comment: @Cerbo, стандарт не предъявляет подобных требований, он отдаёт это на откуп компиляторов(implementation defined). Но все компиляторы делают именно так, т.к. ни один не будет переводить исходник в какую-то внутреннюю кодировку, т.к. он не может знать из какой кодировки ему переводить. Поэтому он просто будет использовать кодировку исходного файла.

Comment: @ixSci: К сожалению, это _не_ так для MS Visual Studio.

Comment: @VladD, что конкретно не так?

Comment: @ixSci: Например, если вы указываете Visual Studio, что кодировка файла — CP866, то литералы будут всё равно компилироваться как будто кодировка файла CP1251 (на русскоязычной Windows). Выглядит как баг, конечно.

Comment: @VladD, кодировка тут будет ANSI, а вот codepage никогда не сохраняется в файле, поэтому когда компилятор «ест» файл он должен выбрать какой-то codepage для исходника, вполне естественно, что он берёт системный CP1251.

Comment: Относительно gcc могу подтвердить, что всюду где я его использовал (linux, windows, hp-ux, bsd, sun-os, solaris, aix), он ничего не делал с такими байтам. Что записали в редакторе (cp866, cp1251, iso8859-5, koi-8r, utf-8 (с другими дела вроде бы не имел)), то и оказывается в константах оттранслированного модуля.

Comment: @Cerbo, не надо править мои ответы.

Comment: @ixSci Почему же? Я думал вы имеете в виду gcc. Важно знать к ками компиляторам относится описанное поведение, не правда ли.

Comment: @Cerbo, потому что я написал то, что написал. Я не имел в виду gcc, я имел в виду все компиляторы.

Comment: @ixSci В таком случае ваш ответ некорректен как минимум в отношении MSVC и вводит в заблуждение, следовательно его нужно минусовать либо править. Такие у нас на SO правила в роде с утра были. Поэтому лучше указать компиляторы.

Comment: @Cerbo, мой ответ вполне корректен, что в нём не так?

Comment: @ixSci В том что он не относится ко все компиляторам! Я сужу с точки зрения начинающего: как имено будет работать его компилятор, на что ему ориентироваться.

Comment: @Cerbo, ещё раз — мой ответ относится ко всем компиляторам, включая MSVC. Если Вы ссылаетесь на то, что указал Vlad, то его ремарка не имеет смысла, о чём я ему написал в чате. Совершенно не имеет смысла говорить о codepage у компилятора, т.к. он не транслирует строки, за исключением тех, что он обязан по стандарту(u8, u, U), поэтому если вы сохраните фалй в KOI8, то строка запишет тот набор байт, который можно будет перевести в человеческий текст имено с codepage KOI8.

Comment: @ixSci: У MSVC **есть** явное указание кодировки файла.

Comment: @VladD, нет, у MSVC **нет** явного указания кодировки файла.

Comment: @ixSci: http://i.stack.imgur.com/UV9WG.png

Comment: @VladD, это диалог сохранения файла в IDE. Никаким боком эта информация к компилятору не относится. Т.е. это фактически конвертация исходника из текущей кодировку, в какую-то другую. Не более того.

Comment: @ixSci Что вы скажете по поводу этого http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#index-fexec-charset-1208

Comment: @Cerbo, а что я должен сказать по этому поводу? В gcc есть настройки, которые позволяют что-то куда-то транслировать. Вы видите связь этих параметров с вопросом? Я — нет.

Answer (score 3):

GCC имеет [опции препроцессора](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#index-fexec-charset-1208) для указания кодировок строковых констант и исходников.

> `-fexec-charset=charset`
>   Устанавливает кодировку строковых и символьных констант исполняемого файла. По-умолчанию используется UTF-8. `charset` может быть именем кодировки которое поддерживается библиотекой iconv установленой в системе.
>
> `-fwide-exec-charset=charset`
>   Устанавливает кодировку, "широких" строковых и символьных констант исполняемого файла. По-умолчанию используется UTF-32 или UTF-16 в зависимости от "ширины" типа wchar_t. Как и вслучае `-fexec-charset`, `charset` может быть именем кодировки которое поддерживается библиотекой iconv установленой в системе.
>
> `-finput-charset=charset`
>   Указывает компилятору кодировку входных файлов. Кодировка используется для перекодирования входных файлов в кодировку используемую компилятором GCC. По-умолчанию `charset` равен системеной кодировке, если системная кодировка не задана или GCC не может ее получить, то в качестве `charset` используется UTF-8. В настоящий момент опция имеет преимущество в случае возникновения конфликтов. `charset` может быть именем кодировки которое поддерживается библиотекой iconv установленой в системе.

Comment: Это документация вводит в заблуждение. И она противоречит экспериментам: если не задавать `input-charset`, то никаких преобразований не будет сделано — стройка будет записана как есть. Либо документация GCC врёт, либо написана косноязычно и имеется в виду нечто другое