# Русский язык в JSON

Tags: c++, json, исключения

Вычитал из [этой статьи](https://habrahabr.ru/company/infopulse/blog/254075/), что есть парсер *JSON*. Удобный парсер, но при вводе значений на русском языке выводится ошибка.

> Возникло необработанное исключение по адресу 0x753BB760

Вот пример кода:

```
nlohmann::json response_json;
auto response_json = nlohmann::json::parse("{ \"Пример\": [\"Нуль\"] }");
```

Вот этот код рабочий:

```
nlohmann::json response_json;
auto response_json = nlohmann::json::parse("{ \"Value\": [\"NULL\"] }");
```

Никто не в курсе как изменить данную ситуацию? Поправить может что-то, чтобы оно работало.

Comment: unicode нужно экранировать для этого парсера

Comment: либо сменить парсер

Comment: Может вам использовать UTF-8 кодировку для json?

Comment: Автор, в какой кодировке файл сохраняете?

Answer (score 1):

Убедитесь, что сохраняете файл с исходным кодом в кодировке UTF-8. Или настройте компилятор [подходящим образом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/461155). Вероятно, самым простым способом будет просто указать префикс `u8` перед строкой с JSON.

N.B.: [Ваша библиотека](https://github.com/nlohmann/json#notes) поддерживает только эту кодировку.

P.S.: Возможно, вам будет удобно использовать сырые С++ строки. Подробнее можно прочитать, например, на [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/69ze775t.aspx).

Ваш пример у меня отлично работает:

```
using namespace nlohmann;
json ex = json::parse(u8R"({ "Пример": [ "Нуль" ] })");
for (json::iterator it = ex.begin(); it != ex.end(); ++it) {
    std::cout << it.key() << ": " << it.value() << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Плюс за  `u8R"(`. Работает ли `cout << ex;` или `for (auto&& p : ex) cout << p << "\n";` или `for (auto&& p : ex) cout << p.key() << " " << p.value() << "\n";`? 2- сам исходник при этом нужно сохранять в ожидаемой компилятором кодировке (не обязательно utf-8). Я представляю это как: компилятор байты из файла с исходным  кодом декодирует в Unicode, используя эту кодировку, затем компилятор кодирует Unicode назад в байты, используя utf-8, благодаря `u8""`, таким образом парсер при исполнении увидит байты, представляющие текст в utf-8 кодир(чтобы голова не болела, можно везде utf-8 использовать).

Comment: @jfs, работают (но не так, как мне хотелось бы) первые два варианта из предложенных вами. А вот показать и имя поля, и значение третьим вариантом не выйдет.